# How do I use pandas to compare a list of numbers to a column in an excel document?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this simple script that creates a list by taking the values out of the column of excel_1 and compares it to the values of a column in excel_2. I want it to return any rows that aren't in the column 'ext_addr_id' in excel_2.

If I hard code the list, it creates the document just fine. But when I create the list with a for loop, then it returns the whole list and doesnt seem to do the comparison, or at least when it does the comparison, it doesn't recognize the numbers in the list as the same as the numbers in excel_2.

I've tried everything and I'm out of ideas, what am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filePath = r'/outputs/coupa_address_id_translation_results.xlsx'
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.remove(filePath)

cust_results = pd.read_excel(r'./data_sources/excel_1.xlsx')
# maybe convert to csv to get access to other libs
# aws_results = pd.read_excel(r'./data_sources/excel_2.xlsx')
aws_results = pd.read_csv(r'./data_sources/excel_2.csv')

missing_addresses = pd.DataFrame()
cust_addr_id_list = []

for cust_row, cust_col in cust_results.iterrows():
    cust_ext_addr_id_column_number = 0  # index begins at 0
    cust_addr_id_list.append(str(cust_results.values[cust_row][cust_ext_addr_id_column_number]).strip())
    # cust_addr_id_list.append(cust_results.values[cust_row][cust_ext_addr_id_column_number])
    
print(cust_addr_id_list)
filter = ~aws_results['ext_addr_id'].isin(cust_addr_id_list)
# filter = ~aws_results['ext_addr_id'].isin(['1253', '2177', '2258'])

# print(filter)

missing_addresses = aws_results[filter]

missing_addresses.to_excel("./outputs/coupa_address_id_translation_results.xlsx")
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

EDIT: Responding to Durtal re: the contents of the cust_addr_id_list, I've
tried it with both strings and integers, and actually this was the crux of my question. The outputs are

`['2339', '2534', '2234', '2340', '2363', '2297', '2834', '2371', '2190', '2373', '2284', '2287', '1821', '1898', '2342', '2374', '2311', '2343', '2344', '2376', '2193', '2192', '2345', '2346', '2191', '2379', '2383', '2293', '1887', '2513', '675', '1888', '2235', '2269', '2270', '2272', '2224', '2223', '1769', '1897', '1771', '2286', '2537', '1899', '2382', '2225', '2283', '2276', '2285', '683', '2161', '2271', '2174', '2173', '1781', '2335', '2347', '2317', '1780', '2521', '1906', '2349', '2328', '2348', '2327', '1782', '2207', '2210', '2840', '2208', '2260', '2184', '2321', '2183', '2182', '2322', '2333', '2350', '2692', '2717', '2690', '2720', '2718', '2719', '2310', '2266', '2313', '1893', '2265', '2314', '2337', '2308', '2309', '2315', '2351', '2352', '1541', '1890', '2298', '1889', '1891', '2240', '2242', '2370', '2217', '2244', '2501', '2301', '2331', '2319', '2238', '1911', '2329', '2689', '2728', '2729', '2688', '2727', '2730', '2731', '2723', '2290', '2687', '2724', '2725', '2726', '2330', '2166', '2168', '2167', '2257', '2169', '1910', '2282', '2209', '2336', '2517', '2171', '2362', '2307', '1883', '2197', '2299', '2320', '1913', '2303', '2318', '2316', '2858', '1903', '1901', '1902', '2300', '1905', '2304', '2326', '2302', '2250', '2393', '2355', '2356', '2366', '2252', '2357', '1894', '2375', '2843', '1909', '2359', '2377', '1895', '2433', '2196', '1907', '1738', '1786', '2237', '2175', '2261', '1784', '2365', '2236', '2259', '2323', '1846', '2443', '2248', '2369', '2204', '2253', '2216', '2212', '2457', '2214', '2213', '1790', '2258', '1920', '2215', '2177', '2178', '2188', '2189', '2636', '2754', '2202', '2263', '2427', '2222', '2262', '2220', '2281', '1900', '2305', '1904', '1908', '2221', '2438', '2360', '2425', '2334', '2761', '2295', '2312', '2361', '2288', '2650', '2543', '2251', '2860', '2735', '2368', '2338', '2228', '2227', '2258']`

and

`[2339, 2534, 2234, 2340, 2363, 2297, 2834, 2371, 2190, 2373, 2284, 2287, 1821, 1898, 2342, 2374, 2311, 2343, 2344, 2376, 2193, 2192, 2345, 2346, 2191, 2379, 2383, 2293, 1887, 2513, 675, 1888, 2235, 2269, 2270, 2272, 2224, 2223, 1769, 1897, 1771, 2286, 2537, 1899, 2382, 2225, 2283, 2276, 2285, 683, 2161, 2271, 2174, 2173, 1781, 2335, 2347, 2317, 1780, 2521, 1906, 2349, 2328, 2348, 2327, 1782, 2207, 2210, 2840, 2208, 2260, 2184, 2321, 2183, 2182, 2322, 2333, 2350, 2692, 2717, 2690, 2720, 2718, 2719, 2310, 2266, 2313, 1893, 2265, 2314, 2337, 2308, 2309, 2315, 2351, 2352, 1541, 1890, 2298, 1889, 1891, 2240, 2242, 2370, 2217, 2244, 2501, 2301, 2331, 2319, 2238, 1911, 2329, 2689, 2728, 2729, 2688, 2727, 2730, 2731, 2723, 2290, 2687, 2724, 2725, 2726, 2330, 2166, 2168, 2167, 2257, 2169, 1910, 2282, 2209, 2336, 2517, 2171, 2362, 2307, 1883, 2197, 2299, 2320, 1913, 2303, 2318, 2316, 2858, 1903, 1901, 1902, 2300, 1905, 2304, 2326, 2302, 2250, 2393, 2355, 2356, 2366, 2252, 2357, 1894, 2375, 2843, 1909, 2359, 2377, 1895, 2433, 2196, 1907, 1738, 1786, 2237, 2175, 2261, 1784, 2365, 2236, 2259, 2323, 1846, 2443, 2248, 2369, 2204, 2253, 2216, 2212, 2457, 2214, 2213, 1790, 2258, 1920, 2215, 2177, 2178, 2188, 2189, 2636, 2754, 2202, 2263, 2427, 2222, 2262, 2220, 2281, 1900, 2305, 1904, 1908, 2221, 2438, 2360, 2425, 2334, 2761, 2295, 2312, 2361, 2288, 2650, 2543, 2251, 2860, 2735, 2368, 2338, 2228, 2227, 2258]`

depending on whether I wrap `(cust_results.values[cust_row][cust_ext_addr_id_column_number]` in a str() (such as in the example) or not.

In neither case does it work. However, if I take a few entries that appear in both lists and pass them directly into the filter variable, such as the `# filter =`  
line commented out, then the script works and returns the correct lines.

Comment: Please provide the output of `print(cust_addr_id_list)`. Be aware that your hard coded list contains strings while `cust_addr_id_list` might contain integers. But without the input files one can only guess. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: there are a number of possibilities: but you could use join functionalites of pandas

Comment: @Durtal I've added the answer to your questions above

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has several issues, but we will stick to your logic for this time.

It is a bad idea to use a name of a built-in-function for a variable. Use `filter_` instead of `filter`, or better: give it an appropriate name like `index_not_matched`.

A recipe for self-help:

If the whole dataframe is returned, this probably means, that your filter-variable contains only `True`. Check this and than inspect why this happens!

Obviously `filter = ~aws_results['ext_addr_id'].isin(cust_addr_id_list)` is not working as expected. Inspect why!

Are the items of both lists of the same datatype? Look at `aws_results.dtypes` and `[type(el) for el in cust_addr_id_list]`.

Possible types are: String, Integer, Float. Make sure both lists are of the same type. Then ensure that both list contain the same values. This should lead you where you want.